# ImageView setScaleX/Y with scale factor < 1

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, scaletype

I have strange behavior with ImageView (scale type = Matrix).

I have some parent view (FrameLayout actually, marked grey on picture). On the top of this FrameLayout my ImageView is located with MATCH_PARENT attributes.

So I expect ImageView should fill parent view. I have Bitmaps with different sizes to set in different cases in my ImageView (with MATRIX ScaleType). Sometimes it is smaller than ParentView, sometimes bigger. I want to adjust bitmap to parent bounds using imageView.setScaleY(scaleFactor) and it totally works if scaleFactor is > 1. But if Bitmap is actually bigger and scaleFactor is < 1, ImageView behaves pretty strange: ImageView's Drawable is scaled correctly and try to fill all parent view, but for some reason ImageView bounds is scaled down (in comparison to MATCH_PARENT). The result is illustrated in picture below (with scale factor ~ 0.5).

**So looks like ImageView size is scaled down with Bitmap and I cannot prevent it with using imageView.setMinimumWidth/Height or LayoutParams.**

Any ideas?

[image]

P.S. I cannot scale ImageView using Matrix transformation (because it is used for different purposes in my app - zoom/move/rotate)

Comment: I think your ImageView is there and you just can't see it.  Try assigning a background color to the ImageView, or even better, add an x&y translation to the matrix i.e. `matrix.postTranslate(x,y)`.  You should be able to see that the ImageView uses the entire area.

Comment: x&y translations just move my bitmap within ImageView "window". But ImageView getWidth() return correct value (same as parent view). How can it help?

Comment: Oh, I see the issue.  You are probably thinking that if the bitmap is bigger, then you need to scale it down more.  Turns out that the ImageView will adjust the size of the bitmap to fit, then that becomes scale == 1.  So you will get the same result with scaling no matter what size bitmap you use.

Comment: So when I scale up a small bitmap - it becomes bigger and ImageView adjust bitmap borders (fill grey area on picture above). And when bitmap is bigger than that grey area - ImageView cannot adjust bitmap (because of MATCH_PARENT attribute). After setScaleX() is called, ImageView is scaled down (to red area borders) + bitmap is scaled down to grey area.
Is it correct? I just cannot understand ImageView rendering order. Bitmap is adjusted to ImageView or vise versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard for me to answer without seeing your code, but I will make a guess.

I think you are confusing *scaling the bitmap within the `ImageView`* and *scaling the `ImageView` widget itself*.  These are two different things.

So you put your `ImageView` inside a `FrameLayout` with `MATCH_PARENT` for width and height.  Now your `ImageView` should be the same size as your `FrameLayout`.  All well and good.

The `ImageView` is a view.  All views can be scaled (and translated and rotated).

When you say `imageView.setScaleX()` and `imageView.setScaleY()`, you are *changing the bounds of the widget*.  Doesn't matter what the layout parameters are, you are changing the size of the view.

Now, `ImageView` is special because it has its own way of scaling the source image *without* changing its bounds.  This is using the `scaleType` attribute.  So with an `ImageView` you can change the size of the image *without changing the bounds of the `ImageView`.*

I wrote a pinch/zoom view and used the `scaleType="matrix"` which is what I think you're doing.  So here's how I solved the problem you seem to be having:

The bitmap comes in with certain dimensions.  The `ImageView` has certain dimensions once it's been laid out.  So let's say the bitmap and the `ImageView` have the same dimensions.  The starting scale for your matrix would be 1.  Very simple.

So what if the dimensions are different?  You would have to compute a starting scale.  Here's how I did it:  I created one `Rect` (src) with the bitmap dimensions, and another `Rect` (dest) with the `ImageView` dimensions.  Then I called `matrix.setRectToRect(src, dest, ScaleToFit.START)`.  This method sets the scale factor on the matrix so that when you apply the matrix on the bitmap (for example `ImageView.setImageMatrix()`), the bitmap is correctly resized to the dimensions of the `ImageView`.

Because you haven't posted any code it's hard for me to know how applicable this is, but hopefully something I posted here will put you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for explaining `ImageView` details. The only problem  - I cannot use `Matrix` transformation in my app because I already used it for image editing and it is very uncomfortable to deal with additional matrix scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution is using matrix transformation.

After deep investigation I found that `setScaleX()` method works in very strange way:

- scale ImageView Bitmap;
- doesnt scale ImageView by itself - imageView.getHeight() returns unscaled value and DeveloperOptions->Show Layout Bounds shows unscaled ImageView;
- **BUT** it scales ImageView's Canvas - so ImageView has correct size, but render Bitmap in **SCALED** Canvas.

Thanks kris larson for help

Answer (score 0):

Add 0.7f
example:
  v.setScaleX(0.9f);